# Pushing arrays in ionic 4

Tags: arrays, angular, google-maps, ionic4

I have a Ionic App and I am trying to get latitude and longitude from data api as Json format, for a flight route. The data contains arrays . I want to push arrays into Google maps `polylin`e to get flight route on map but I get an error when I run the app.

My full code:

```js
export class HomePage{
  map: GoogleMap;
  latitude: any;
  longitude: any;
  constructor(
    public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    private platform: Platform,
    private http: HTTP
    ) { }

ngOnInit() {
    // Since ngOnInit() is executed before `deviceready` event,
    // you have to wait the event.
    this.platform.ready();
    this.getmarker();


  }

  getmarker(){
    this.http.get('xxxxxxx/v1/flight.json?flightId=201',{},{})
    .then(data=>{

      this.latitude = JSON.parse(data.data).result.response.data.flight.track.latitude
      this.longitude = JSON.parse(data.data).result.response.data.flight.track.longitude
      console.log(this.latitude,this.longitude)

      this.loadMap()
    })
  }

  loadMap() {


    let HND_AIR_PORT = this.latitude;
    let SFO_AIR_PORT = this.longitude

    let AIR_PORTS = [
      HND_AIR_PORT,
      SFO_AIR_PORT
    ];

    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas');

    let polyline: Polyline = this.map.addPolylineSync({
      points: AIR_PORTS,
      color: '#AA00FF',
      width: 10,
      geodesic: true,
      clickable: true  // clickable = false in default
    });

    polyline.on(GoogleMapsEvent.POLYLINE_CLICK).subscribe((params: any) => {
      let position: LatLng = <LatLng>params[0];

      let marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync({
        position: position,
        title: position.toUrlValue(),
        disableAutoPan: true
      });
      marker.showInfoWindow();
    });
  }
}
```

The error I am getting:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'getPosition' in undefined
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'getPosition' in undefined
    at getLatLng (plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/Common.js:544)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.convertToPositionArray (plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/Common.js:575)
    at Map.addPolyline (plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/Map.js:1231)
    at vendor.js:76340
    at GoogleMap.push../node_modules/@ionic-native/google-maps/index.js.GoogleMap.addPolylineSync (vendor.js:76352)
    at HomePage.push../src/app/home/home.page.ts.HomePage.loadMap (home-home-module.js:126)
    at home-home-module.js:114
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (polyfills.js:2749)
    at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:51123)
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:3189)
    at polyfills.js:3254
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:2781)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:51114)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:2780)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (polyfills.js:2553)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (polyfills.js:2959)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I describe how to reach the answer with steps:

### step1: understanding what happends

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'getPosition' in undefined
    at getLatLng (plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/Common.js:544)
```

Regarding of the error log, the error occurs at here.

```js
function getLatLng(target) {
  return 'getPosition' in target ? target.getPosition() : {
    'lat': parseFloat(target.lat, 10),
    'lng': parseFloat(target.lng, 10)
  };
}
```

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/blob/d500b295b983c597dd99003ce8151c9d9d6e9ca5/www/Common.js#L542-L547

The error says the plugin code tries to check "getPosition" for undefined.
It means the variable `target` is undefined.

At this time, we can get the reason of the error that `you specified incorrect value`.

### step2: find another hints from the log

Let's find out `where` the bug in your code.
Checking the error log, you would also notice this error log.

```
at GoogleMap.push../node_modules/@ionic-native/google-maps/index.js.GoogleMap.addPolylineSync (vendor.js:76352)
```

It seems the error occurs at the below code.

```ts
let polyline: Polyline = this.map.addPolylineSync({
  points: AIR_PORTS,
  color: '#AA00FF',
  width: 10,
  geodesic: true,
  clickable: true  // clickable = false in default
});
```

The plugin tried to get `lat` and `lng`, but you specified the variable `AIR_PORTS`.

### step3: figure out your bug

Let's check the variable `AIR_PORTS`.

```
let HND_AIR_PORT = this.latitude;
let SFO_AIR_PORT = this.longitude

let AIR_PORTS = [
  HND_AIR_PORT,
  SFO_AIR_PORT
];
```

If you are familiar with Google Maps API, you probably notice what wrong is.
The questioner specified `latitude` for `HND_AIR_PORT`, and `longitude` for `SFO_AIR_PORT`.

`xxx_AIR_PORT` means one location.
It means the variable should be paired of `latitude` and `longitude`.

So, at least the variable should be formed like this:

```
let HND_AIR_PORT = {
  lat: ...,
  lng: ...
};
```

At this time, we figured out where the bug in your code is.

### step4: search the answer on Google

Okay, let's search the correct answer.
The keyword is `addPolylineSync`.
Searching on the Google, you would reach this code and demo.

**code**
https://github.com/mapsplugin/ionic-googlemaps-quickdemo-v4/blob/master/src/app/polyline/polyline.page.ts

**demo**
https://mapsplugin.github.io/ionic-googlemaps-quickdemo-v4/polyline

[image]

In the demo code, you can see the answer.

```
let HND_AIR_PORT = {lat: 35.548852, lng: 139.784086};
let SFO_AIR_PORT = {lat: 37.615223, lng: -122.389979};
let HNL_AIR_PORT = {lat: 21.324513, lng: -157.925074};


let AIR_PORTS = [
  HND_AIR_PORT,
  HNL_AIR_PORT,
  SFO_AIR_PORT
];
```

https://github.com/mapsplugin/ionic-googlemaps-quickdemo-v4/blob/master/src/app/polyline/polyline.page.ts#L30-L33

### conclusion

I teach how to approach to unknown error, not just answer.

When you meet a next error,

1. check the error log,
2. check the code (if possible),
3. understand what the code wants to do,
4. search the bug in your code first,
5. read documentation,
6. you can not solve the problem even following the above steps, ask someone.

By the way, the code of `cordova-plugin-googlemaps` and `@ionic-native/googlemaps` are all full opened.
No hidden code at all ;)

Comment: Thank you for answer . l really appreciate